# RCTFatal+668 error in TestFlight but runs perfectly fine in Expo-Go

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, testflight

Currently, I have an expo-cli managed app. When I run it through the Expo Go app on the simulator or my actual phone, it works perfectly, but when I build it through eas build and submit it to TestFlight, it crashes upon clicking a button. It says that the error is an RCTFatal+668 and -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:extraDataAsJSON:]. Here is an attachment of what it says (the app name is blurred for privacy reasons):
[Click Here to View the XCode error statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjPvV.png)

Also, when I add `AsyncStorage.clear()` in the code and run the expo-cli app through Expo-Go app, it says that there is something related to the AsyncStorage and RCTAsyncLocalStorage in the terminal (at least I think that's what it's saying). Here is the picture of the log in the terminal (I blurred some of the lines in the terminal for privacy reasons): [Click Here to View the Terminal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CneC3.png).

Are these in any way related? And how can I solve the first issue so that when I deploy my app to TestFlight, it doesn't crash? I've read other articles that mention the stack navigator, so I think it might have to do with that as well.

Here is my package.json:

```html
{
  "name": "{not here for privacy reasons}",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
    "eas": "^0.1.0",
    "expo": "~46.0.16",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-flat-button": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-swipeable": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-swipeout": "^2.3.6",
    "skyward-rest": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I had edited skyward-rest in the node_modules folder because that is where it was downloaded. However, `EAS build` also runs `npm install`, resetting all of my changed to the skyward-rest dependency. To solve the problem, I moved the skyward-rest dependency out of the node_modules folder.